# Can a CircleCI workflow create a Docker image in a first step and then test that Docker image in a second step?

Tags: docker, circleci, circleci-2.0

I'm new to CircleCI workflows and I would like to create a workflow with two steps.

1. The first step (build job) will build and push a Docker image to a Docker registry with a certain tag. After successful termination of the first
   step it will trigger a second workflow step and handover the tag of
   the Docker image.
2. The seconds step will then download the image by handed over by step 1 (e.g. using an ENV variable). Something like

```
version: 2
    jobs:
      build:
        docker:
          - image: docker.repo.ch/image:${TAG}
```

Is there some mechanism to hand over a value as a paramter from one build job to another one in within a CircleCI workflow?

Comment: are you going to push it to a docker registry or just pass it from job to job?

Comment: The idea is to push the image in step 1 to a docker registry and the consume (pull) it in step 2.

Comment: edited accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since every run step is a new shell, environment variables are
>   not shared across steps. If you need an environment variable to be
>   accessible in more than one step, export the value using BASH_ENV.

https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#setting-an-environment-variable-in-a-step

### **Export a var to the next job:**

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  pass_tag:
    jobs:
    - create_tag
    - use_tag:
        requires:
        - create_tag

executors:
  node:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:4.8.2

jobs:
  create_tag:
    executor: node
    steps:
    - run: echo "export MY_TAG=$CIRCLE_SHA1" >> $BASH_ENV
  use_tag:
    executor: node
    steps:
    - run: echo $MY_TAG
```

### **Push & Use docker images:**

use CircleCI `orbs` (like a library) to build and push the image:

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
    aws-ecr: circleci/aws-ecr@6.7.0

workflows:
  version: 2
  example:
   jobs:
      - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image:
          account-url: DEV_AWS_ECR_ACCOUNT_URL
          aws-access-key-id: DEV_ACCESS_KEY_ID
          aws-secret-access-key: DEV_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          create-repo: true
          repo: '${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}'
          region: AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
          tag: '${CIRCLE_SHA1}'
      -  pull_image:
          requires:
              - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image

jobs:
    pull_image:
        *** pull and use your image here ***
```